# universal app target for iphone & ipad - 2 app error

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, sdk, iphone-sdk-3.2

Really would appreciate it if you can help me with something. I have searched every websites and apple documentation but cannot find an answer for the following issue I have:

I have upgraded an iphone app with the intention of having 1 universal 'target' for the iphone and ipad. The problem is that I have 2 products. i.e. Perk.app and Perk-Upgraded.app

How can I combine these to 1 or can I add a new product app that will differentiate the device (I can do that part) and then launch the relevant iphone or ipad product? (this is the part I cant do).

I have been looking at this for months... believe me im pulling my hair out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Wazacko

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually have two distinct apps and then launch the appropriate one. If I understand you correctly what you actually need is to be able to adapt your layout according to the device. For this purpose I used the guide here: http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/44472
It helped me a lot.